# What's the proper query for this. (needs orderby, make some of the values be last and more) MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Table: Users, Students, Groups

Users:
Rows: `Username`
Values: `Teacher1`, `Teacher2`, `Teacher3`, `Teacher4`

Students:
Rows: `grpID`, `Name`
Values: (1, John), (1, Joe), (1, Rose), (2, Gina), (2, Mark), (2, Jack), (3, Ted), (4, Fred)

Groups:
Rows: `grpID`, `Handler`
Values (1, Teacher1), (2, Teacher2), (3, Teacher3), (4, Teacher4)

[image]

I want to query that when someone is logged in (let's say Teacher1)

```
Select `Name` from Students where (I don't know the proper condition here) Order by `Name`
```

but here's the result that I want:

```
Fred
Gina
Jack
Mark
Ted
Joe
John
Rose
```

I want those 3 students handled by Teacher1 (as example user who logged in) to be the last record to be shown on the result of the query.

Comment: How does your database indicate logged-in status?

Comment: ahm.. I got a session on a php file. It may be longer if we'd do it that way. Let's just say part of the condition is `where Handler = "Teacher1"` can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethings loke this

```
select `name` from Students 
inner join Groups on Students.groupID = Groups.grpID
where groups.Handler = 'Teacher1'
order by `name`;
```

otherwise if you want the students order by name you simply use

```
Select `name` from Students 
order by `name`;
```

Comment: there there, so its the `inner join` something that I don't know much. hehe. Thanks for the help @scaisEdge

Comment: I have a problem with this. I followed that query and it gave me a result of only the 3 students handled by teacher1. but I want it to have all the records shown (just the 3 of them being last) I think it's a `THEN` clause that is needed here but still I don't know the proper syntax. PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: You want the name related to a teacher (eg: teacher 1 or to all the students indipendently of the teachers.. ) i have update the answer.. anyway.. give me a feedback

Comment: no no no, not just the students related to teacher 1. All the students which should be ordered by name but having all the students of teacher 1 on the last rows.

Comment: Which is the logic related to your question... .. seems without logic.  explain me your goal  in simple words.

Comment: seriously speaking, I can't put it to words :( . Nevermind this. I'll try to take this my own now. anyway. your first answer already helped a lot. Thanks